# How to configure simpleSAMLphp as an OpenID consumer?

Tags: php, openid

We are using [simpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org) for single-sign-on and would like to authenticate users via several remote OpenID providers.

What are the specific attributes necessary, in the authsources.php openid array, to get simpleSAMLphp to work with any specific OpenID provider?

A working example would be very much appreciated, and will be added to the simpleSAMLphp wiki.

Comment: Did you setup something which work since the time you posted this question ?

Comment: We added a [service provider configuration](https://github.com/educloudalliance/educloud-sso/blob/master/modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php) to our [single-sign-on project](https://github.com/educloudalliance/educloud-sso).